# Модифицировать описание кода

Tags: pascal

Как улучшить описание кода:

```
function FormatFilePath(FilePath, Mask: String): String;
var
  Disc, Directory, FileName, Extension: String;
begin
  // Удалить ведущие и хвостовые пробелы
  FilePath := Trim(FilePath);
  try
    // В полном имени файла FilePath найти:
    //   1) имя диска (не работает, если FilePath - сетевой путь)
    Disc := GetFirstRegExpMatch(FilePath, '^([A-Z]{1}):\\');
    //   2) директорию
    Directory := GetFirstRegExpMatch(FilePath, '^[A-Z]{1}:\\(.*)\\[^\\]+');
    //   3) имя файла
    FileName := GetFirstRegExpMatch(FilePath, '^[A-Z]{1}:\\.*\\([^\\]+)\.[^\.\\]+$');
    //   4) расширение файла
    Extension := GetFirstRegExpMatch(FilePath, '^[A-Z]{1}:\\.*\\[^\\]+\.([^\.\\]+)$');
  except
    // Если полное имя файла задано не верно, вернуть пустую строку
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  // Скомпоновать полученные значения (диск, директорию, имя файла и расширение)
  // в строку, как указано в маске Mask
  Result := Mask;
  // Заменить %D на имя диска
  Result := Replace(Result, '%D', Disc);
  // Заменить %P на путь
  Result := Replace(Result, '%P', Directory);
  // Заменить %N на имя файла
  Result := Replace(Result, '%N', FileName);
  // Заменить %E на расширение
  Result := Replace(Result, '%E', Extension);
end;
```

Comment: Во-первых, грамматика («задано неверно» без пробела, точки на концах предложений).  Во-вторых, некоторые комментарии у вас типа [«это мост»](https://abstrusegoose.com/432), особенно в конце (если, конечно, это не требование ВУЗа, как у нас бывает).

Comment: Лучшее описание кода комментариями — почти полное их отсутствие, кроме неочевидных моментов с объяснениями, почему сделано так, а не иначе. Посмотрите сами, `// Заменить %E на расширение` только усложняет читаемость и добавляет лишнюю строку, которую надо поддерживать, но не добавляет никакой новой информации